# Regular expression for validating month

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

What is the regular expression for validating a month with the leading zero?

Passes regular expression:

> 01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12

Fails regular expression:

```
1, 00, 13 and up.
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
/^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/
```

Comment: Getting rid of the parentheses can improve the performance of this expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
/^01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12$/
```

Comment: Expressed more succinctly in [Seb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878010/regular-expression-for-validating-month/2878016#2878016)

Comment: Not a very sexy solution... =(

Comment: It may not be the more succinct, but it is faster than /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])$/, even /^0[1-9]|1[0-2]$/, when used with grep against 1,000,000 test data that I generated.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a better one, it accepts '05', but also '5' as a month:

```
/(^0?[1-9]$)|(^1[0-2]$)/
```

Answer (score -1):

this will work

```
/(0[1-9])|(1[012])/
```